# Why instances of `Class` and `Class<?>` has different behavior where it shouldn't be so?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, behavior

**I've found that:**

When I'm using `Class<?>` to declare variable, `getAnnotation` acts as:

```
public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass)
```

, but when I'm using `Class` to declare variable, `getAnnotation` acts as:

```
public Annotation getAnnotation(Annotation annotationClass)
```

, so I couldn't compile code, that uses passed annotation class specific methods.

---

*e.g.: I could compile`((Class<?>)clazz).getAnnotation(Human.class).age()`, but couldn't compile `((Class)clazz).getAnnotation(Human.class).age()`, where `clazz` is some `Class` instance, and `Human` is annotation interface, that have `age` method.*

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It would really help if you'd give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but I *suspect* you're running into a raw type.

---

[JLS — 4.8 Raw Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8):

> A raw type is define to be either:
>
> - The name of a generic type declaration used without any accompanying actual type parameters.
> - Any non-static type member of a raw type R that is not inherited from a superclass or superinterface of R.

[JLS — 4.6 Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108979):

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables).

---

So it's actually that this method:

```
public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass)
```

is erased to this:

```
public Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationClass)
```

That's why you can call `getAnnotation`, but the return type won't be `Human`, it'll just be `Annotation`.

Comment: My problem was, that I'v thought, that, if generic method doesn't use overclass type parameter (but use only parameters, that belongs only to this method (appears in declaration of the method)), it will not be erased, because all generic mechanics is clear in this case.

Comment: @Errandir: Unfortunately not. I think the basic principle was meant to be that raw types were for use from generic-unaware code, and that *new* code wouldn't use them. It hasn't quite worked that way...

Comment: I see. To be more precise, reason for raw types to be is a java-code backward compatibility, because the same source code compiled by a generic-unaware compiler and by a generic-aware one supposed to behave the same.